# Cant figure out how to read fractions in txt file and output to a different txt file in Java

Tags: java

I am in fundamentals of programming 1 and my professor has asked us to create a txt file with 10 fractions, create a program that would read the fractions, add them, get the sum, and find the average, and finally export the results to a different txt file.

So far I have found out how to create and write to a file, but reading the fractions in my txt file is proving increasingly difficult. It compiles but keeps reading out that exceptions had to e made whenever it is ran.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FahrDylanFileInputOutput {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double sum = 0.0;
        File input = new File("dylfahrinput.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(input);
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            double fraction = Double.parseDouble(line);
            sum = sum + fraction;
        }
        double avg = sum / 10;

        inputFile.close();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("dylfahroutput.txt");
        pw.println("Sum is : " + sum + "\n Average is: " + avg);
        // add this to the end of the overall program.
        pw.close();

        System.out.println("Data has been written to the txt file.");
    }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?
The fractions are 1/10 - 9/10

Update: here is the complete code now, still same command prompt message:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double numsum = 0.0;
    double densum = 0.0;
    File input = new File("dylfahrinput.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(input);

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        String[] fract = line.split("/");
        int num = Integer.valueOf(fract[0]);
        int den = Integer.valueOf(fract[1]);
        double fraction = num / den;
        numsum = (numsum + num);
        densum = den;
    }
    double avg = numsum / 10;
    inputFile.close();

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("dylfahroutput.txt");
    pw.println("Sum is : " + numsum + "/" + densum + "\n Average is: " + avg);
    // add this to the end of the overall program.
    pw.close();

    System.out.println("Data has been written to the txt file.");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is wrong with this program? What is the actual and expected behavior?

Comment: The problem is that when ran the cmd prompt reads:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 0"
          at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.valueof(Integer.java:582)
at FahrDylanFileInputOutput.main(FahrDylanFileInputOutput.java:23)

Comment: `still same comand prompt message` and what is this message? And your posted stacktrace shows that have values like `"1 0"` in your file. Why is there a whitespace between these two numbers?

Comment: Tom, that is the message that is in the command prompt when ran. I am not sure why there is a space between the 1 and 0

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Check your input file for extra spaces.  It sounds like there might be an entry that was entered as e.g. `2/1 0`, which means that you would be trying to parse "1 0" as an integer.  2) May as well start learning now: `System.out.println()` is your friend.  Use it, and use it a lot.  (And later, learn to use something like log4j.)  Try putting `System.out.println("Parsed " + fract[0] + ", " + fract[1]);` right after your `line.split("/");`

Comment: ok tom its not 1 space 0, its 10, the denominator it cannot read it

Comment: Please add the file content to your question.

Comment: thank you so much Eric! here are the results:
it prints off parsed, the numerator , and the denominator. Now how should I add them all together, get the sum and finally the average?

Comment: Thank you eric!! I got the sum and average now, to translate it to look more like a fraction and reformat the average

Comment: Now, how would you change your code so you can handle any number of fractions, not just ten? ;-)

Comment: @Eric so if I understand correctly, I am to use a line.split('/')
then identify the numerator and denominator in specific values etc, then just separate the two etc. Oh god thank yall so much! I look forward to the rest of my academic career with this kind of stuff, and hopefully my actual working career too

Comment: If you want to thank people, it's nice to upvote the answers and comments that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you're mostly on the right track, at least as far as reading the file, having a variable store the sum of the fractions you've read, etc.

Presumably `line` will contain string values like `"1/10"` or `"6/10"` as you iterate through the lines of the file.

I recommend checking the documentation for `Double.parseDouble(String)`, because it's expecting a decimal-formatted number.

So, you're going to have to parse the string yourself.  How would you do that?

> You have two integers separated by a '/' character. How can you get the integers by themselves?

> Try `String.split()`

> `new String("I love pizza").split(" ")` will give you ["I", "love", "pizza"].
>  `new String("243/19").split("/")` will give you ["243","19"].

Now, let's assume you have a couple of integers, representing the numerator and the denominator.  You have a number of options in terms of how to deal with them.

The simplest would be to just add the numerators together and ignore the denominator.

Comment: ok, so I took your advice along with Abbé Résina's advice. here is the code now:
   double numsum = 0.0;
   double densum = 0.0;
   File input = new File("dylfahrinput.txt");
   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(input);

   while (inputFile.hasNext() )
   {
    String line = inputFile.nextLine();
    String[] fract = line.split("/");
    int num = Integer.valueOf(fract[0]);
    int den = Integer.valueOf(fract[1]);
    double fraction = num / den;
    numsum = (numsum + num);
    densum = den;
   }
    double avg = numsum / 10;
   inputFile.close();

Comment: I just corrected my answer (casting to a double for the numerator). I think the solution is more general if for instance you have denominators different from 10.

Comment: @AbbéRésina Right; had the question included a need for denominators other than 10, I would have suggested something more like C.W.'s Fraction class.  But that's more complicated than I think the poster would have liked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one fraction per line, e.g. your file is

```
1/10
9/10
```

Then you have to replace the line :

```
double fraction = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

By

```
String[] fract = line.split("/");
int num = Integer.valueOf(fract[0]);
int den = Integer.valueOf(fract[1]);
double fraction = (double)num / den;
```

Comment: did this, but same result

Comment: @DylanF please give your input file.

Comment: Not sure how to enclose the file within this comment, first time dude here on this site. but here is the contents:
2/10 
1/10 
3/10 
6/10 
7/10 
4/10 
5/10 
1/10 
8/10 
9/10

input file is dylfahrinput.txt

Comment: Your code will always "return" `0.0` if the fractions are from `1/10` till `9/10`.

Comment: @Tom, yes, just a matter of getting the numerator as a Double or casting.

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble()` doesn't handle strings representing fractions, like `"1/10"`, only strings representing decimal numbers, like `"0.1"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to have a program read the file, parse the file, do the math, then output to a new file?

First off computer do not think in fractions, it is all 0's or 1's.

What you are going to have to do is create a Fraction Class

Your class should have a Numerator of Int Type, and a Denominator of Int Type.
You are also going to want to have couple of function to change the denominator that in turn changes the Numerator.

You should then have a class that can do the math with 2 fraction classes.

I would also make sure your fraction class has a toString() override as well.

This is if your Professor wants Fractions in the output file.

Also some comments on your code.

If you are inputting from a Text file, and you are dividing by 10... Tisk tisk,

You should be Counting the number of fractions you are finding in the text file.

Just a heads up.

UPDATE

Looking at your current code with denominator sum.... bad bad bad math.

Here is your Fraction Class:

```
public class Fraction
{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    private Fraction(){}

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public void multiplyDenominatorByFactor(int x)
    {
       this.numerator = this.numerator*x;
       this.denominator = this.denominator*x;
    }

    public void simplfy()
    {
        //... think this one out.
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ""+this.numerator+"/"+this.denominator+"\n";
    }
}
```

Seeing how this is a class on how to learn programming/java I would also consult your book. I am not going to do your homework for you. Also make sure you do not break the rules of math.

Also if your teacher does not need the results in fractions then you can just convert fraction to doubles or floats by dividing the numerator by the denominator using the split method every one keeps recommending.

If your teacher wants fractions as the returned value, your most accurate results are going to come from keeping your fractions in fraction form. Other wise if accuracy is not required you can convert decimals back into fractions.

Again just think about how you would do it on paper and duplicate that into code. Take a bit of imagination.

Comment: Can you help me create this class and all that would work with the code I have, I have not learned how to create a fraction class or something like that yet. also are you implying that I must use an array if I am to get the averae of the listed fractions?

Comment: Can you help me create a fraction class, I have yet to learn how to do that. Also what is a method I can get the average from the fraction values read from the txt file?

Comment: What is the purpose of a private non-argument constructor if you never call it? And you wrote `class` and `return` wrong (mind the case sensitivity).

Comment: if you do not make the private constructor, it will still be there and be able to be used.

Comment: @C.W. Just remove it, if you don't need it. And now, it won't be there if you don't add it manually.